# Slot prop within _layout.svelte not passing prop

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm working on a Sapper project and I'd like to load in some async data into the layout before loading in the slots. I've found that within a _layout.svelte file, I'm unable to pass props to the slot.

```
//_layout.svelte
<slot foo={"hello"}></slot>

//index.svelte
<script>
  export let foo;
  alert(foo); // returns undefined
</script>
```

Has anyone run into this? I imagine I could work around it by just loading in all the data I need on every slot/subpage. The only way I'm able to set a slot prop is by accessing it manually.

```
$$props.$$scope.ctx.level1.props.foo = "hello"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing data like this doesn't seem to work. You can make use of the [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext) though:

```
// in _layout.svelte
import {setContext} from 'svelte';
setContext('foo', foo);
```

```
// in index.svelte
import {getContext} from 'svelte';
const foo = getContext('foo');
```

Comment: Accepted, thank you! It's less boilerplate than using a store and it seems works similarly to prop storage.