# Pass variable up from page to svelte layout via slot

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

So I can't figure a way to pass a variable up in my `__layout` variable from the component displayed in the `<slot>`.

I tried a few things, using `bind:` or `let:` on the slot but it doesn't  work. I get `'myvar' is not a valid binding` or `<slot> cannot have directives`.
I also tried to export or not the variable on the layout, but I really cannot make it work...

Here is what I have:

```html
 <!-- __layout.svelte -->
<script>
export let myvar = undefined;
</script>

<main>
  <slot myvar={myvar}></slot>
  <p>Layout myvar: {myvar}</p>  <!-- << This will stay undefined -->
</main>
```

```html
 <!-- mypage.svelte -->
<script>
import MyComponent from "$lib/my_component.svelte";
export let myvar;
let a_list_of_things = [1,2,3,4]
</script>

<main>
  {#each a_list_of_things as thing}
    <MyComponent bind:myvar={myvar} thing={thing}/>  <!-- The variable is binded here -->
  {/each}
  <p>mypage myvar: {myvar}</p>   <!-- << This will get the good value -->
</main>
```

```html
 <!-- my_component.svelte -->
<script>
import IconButton from '@smui/icon-button'

export let myvar;
export let thing;
</script>

<div>
  <IconButton class="material-icons" on:click={() => myvar='something'} >
    autorenew
  </IconButton>  <!-- << We change the value on:click here -->

</div>
```

So the main goal is to have an equivalent to `bind:myvar=myvar` on the layout level (for the `<slot></slot>`.

I tried understanding the [documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot-slot-key-value) about it without much success, it seems to be more about the component slot than the layout one.

---

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60921566/17965313) which advise to use a store in sapper (the old name for sveltekit) not sure it is up to date with the last version of sveltekit, is this the way to go  ? Or is there another way ?

[Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608454/17965313) advise using a context. What do you think ?

---

Why do i need this ?

So I have the structure of my app like this:

```
__layout
 ├─ header (menu)
 ├─ my_page (<slot>)
 │   └ my_component (many)
 └ interactive banner
```

That display it like so:

```
[ Header Menu ]

Content of the page
 - component 1
 - component 2
 - component n

[ Current component: 2 ] << Updated when click on an elem in the component
```

The `component` define what the interactive banner should display. Also clicking on the `interactive banner` can change the state displayed in the `components`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this banner message seems to be a piece of global state, a store would be a good solution here. Context would only be necessary if you need to have different banners for different component trees on the page.

Something like this would work:

```js
// src/lib/message.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export default writable('Default message');
```

```svelte
<!-- src/routes/__layout.svelte -->
<script>
    import message from '$lib/message';
</script>

<slot />
<p>{$message}</p>
```

```
<!-- src/routes/index.svelte -->
<script>
    import message from '$lib/message';

    function update() {
        $message = 'New message';
    }
</script>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button on:click={update}>Update message</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked ! Could you add an explanation of the magic behind please ? I think it is important to understand why we do things...

Comment: In `message.js` we create and export Svelte store. Any component can import and subscribe to the store with the `$store` syntax. When the store is updated, anyone subscribing to the store will be notified. This allows us to update the store in `index.svelte` and automatically receive the new value in `__layout.svelte`. I highly recommend going through the [Svelte tutorial on stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores) if you haven't already, since they're an important Svelte concept.

Comment: This answer clearly gives a solution, but is it the only solution? 
Is there a way to bind to a <slot> or doesn't that work at all?

Answer (score -1):

I give below an example with named slots, also unnamed ->

**In Slot.svelte**

```
<script>
  let content ='lorem'
</script>


<slot name='named-slot' >
{content}
</slot>
```

**In Parent component**

```
<script>
 import Data from './Slot.svelte'
 let newData=' new content'
</script>

 
 <Data>  
 <svelte:fragment slot='named-slot' let:newData={content}>
  {newData} 
 </svelte:fragment>

 </Data>
```

*And exmaple for unnamed slot ->*

**In Slot.svelte**

```
<script>
      let content ='lorem'
    </script>
    
    <slot  >
    {content}
    </slot>
```

**In Parent component**

```
<script>
 import Data from './Slot.svelte'
 let newData=' new content'
</script>
    
 

 <Data let:newData={content}> 
  {newData}
   </Data>
```

Comment: But this doesn't work with a layout, has the slot is defined by the route ? or Am I missing something ?